# How do I get an element from a <td> which is inside a ListView control using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, listview, linkbutton

Here's my situation... I'm trying to make a table row clickable. Inside this row is a TD that has a linkbutton with the click event that i want to trigger from javascript. The problem is, the table is inside a ListView, which means I can't access the table or the row directly, I have to get the ListView object first before i can get to the linkbutton to call its click event... I'm having a tough time writing the javascript for this... please help... thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide the snippet of code that shows how your elements are placed inside each others?

Comment: Here's a snippet of the code...

<asp:ListView ID="lvActivity" runat="server" EnableModelValidation="true"  DataSourceID="cdsActivity">
<ItemTemplate>
 <div>
  <table>
   <tr id="clickableRow" style="width: 310px;padding-bottom:0px;" onclick="rowClick()">
    <td>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="lbActivityName" runat="server" Text='Text'
         CssClass="ActivityNameLink" OnClick="Details" />
    </td>
   </tr>

Answer (score 0):

You can access to any object from anywhere using its ID.

```
//Access to the row
var theRow = document.getElementById('clickableRow');

//Access to the LinkButton inside the TD 
var theButton = document.getElementById('lbActivityName');
```

Also note that the ID's are case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried doing that but it doesn't see it since the control I'm trying to get is inside a ListView Control... it just doesn't let me... it says that it doesn't exist in the context.

Comment: Hmm oh well that is kind of weird.
What happens if you parse document.getElementById('IvActivity').childNodes; ?

You should be able to access these elements using DOM navigation.
But I still don't understand why you cannot directly access it..

Answer (score 0):

Each of the buttons you are creating as the template is rendered are going to have a slightly different client ID.  You can verify this by right clicking on the page and selecting View Source.  I think what you need to do is change the following:

```
<tr id="clickableRow" style="width: 310px;padding-bottom:0px;" onclick="rowClick()">
```

to something like:

```
<tr id="clickableRow" style="width: 310px;padding-bottom:0px;" onclick="rowClick('<%=lbActivityName.ClientID %>')">
```

Then change the javascript to use that string in your getElementById.  You may also have to do the same with theRow.

Hopefully that makes sense.